# curl not returning any output for certain websites

Tags: html, curl, command-line

I am looking to buy a product that's currently out of stock. To receive up-to-date information when a product goes in stock I set up a program to alert me when the HTML of a webpage changes to in stock.

To grab the HTML of a page I use curl to get info and read its contents.

For some websites likes https://www.amazon.com/ or https://www.bhphotovideo.com/ I can perfectly grab the data by running the following command:
`curl https://www.amazon.com/`

Where I run into an issue is with https://www.bestbuy.com/ When I to run any curl commands for Best Buy it's like the command is mid execution(like a loop with no exit condition). In an attempt to get more info I added few additional params to figure out the issue but was left with more questions. For Best Buy I ran the following:
`curl -iLv --max-redirs -1 https://www.bestbuy.com/`

Running verbose mode I get the following without curl execution ever completing:

```
    *   Trying 23.47.206.225...
    * TCP_NODELAY set
    * Connected to www.bestbuy.com (23.47.206.225) port 443 (#0)
    * schannel: SSL/TLS connection with www.bestbuy.com port 443 (step 1/3)
    * schannel: checking server certificate revocation
    * schannel: sending initial handshake data: sending 186 bytes...
    * schannel: sent initial handshake data: sent 186 bytes
    * schannel: SSL/TLS connection with www.bestbuy.com port 443 (step 2/3)
    * schannel: failed to receive handshake, need more data
    * schannel: SSL/TLS connection with www.bestbuy.com port 443 (step 2/3)
    * schannel: encrypted data got 3762
    * schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 3762 length 4096
    * schannel: sending next handshake data: sending 126 bytes...
    * schannel: SSL/TLS connection with www.bestbuy.com port 443 (step 2/3)
    * schannel: encrypted data got 242
    * schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 242 length 4096
    * schannel: SSL/TLS handshake complete
    * schannel: SSL/TLS connection with www.bestbuy.com port 443 (step 3/3)
    * schannel: stored credential handle in session cache
    > GET / HTTP/1.1
    > Host: www.bestbuy.com
    > User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
    > Accept: */*
    >
```

PS I have tried different amounts for redirects from none to infinite and all have the same results so I'm not quite sure if it's a redirect issue.

Edit 1: From an answer below it was suggested to try changing the user-agent and enable compression. I tried this via command line but --compress wasn't included with libcurl, so I instead am running the code through Visual Studio

```
CURL* easyhandle = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.bestbuy.com/");
curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "big-floppy-donkey-balls");
curl_easy_perform(easyhandle);
curl_easy_cleanup(easyhandle);
```

but even with this approach I still can't grab the page. I only see the following:

```
    *   Trying 23.47.206.225:443...
    * Connected to www.bestbuy.com (23.47.206.225) port 443 (#0)
    > GET / HTTP/1.1
    Host: www.bestbuy.com
    User-Agent: big-floppy-donkey-balls
    Accept: */*
    Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

(I tried all forms of encoding but none worked, so I'm not sure if it's actually working)

Comment: maybe the site blocks automatic requests from bots, try setting additional headers like user-agent

Comment: @NikosM. bingo, it runs on a user-agent blacklist, in addition to blocking any request lacking `Accept-Encoding` ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first off, [www.bestbuy.com](http://www.bestbuy.com) runs on a user-agent blacklist, and `User-Agent: curl` is blacklisted. but for example `big-floppy-donkey-balls` is not blacklisted. furthermore, [www.bestbuy.com](http://www.bestbuy.com) blocks any request that does not offer to use compression and curl by default does not offer compression, but curl has built-in support for compression which can be enabled with the `--compressed` flag, fixing both of those gives us:

```sh
$ curl --user-agent 'big-floppy-donkey-balls' --compressed 'https://www.bestbuy.com/'
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
  <meta name="keywords" content=" best buy international, best buy countries" />
  <meta name="description" content="Shop online at Best Buy in your country and language of choice. Best Buy provides online shopping in a number of countries and languages."
  />
  <link rel="icon" href="https://www.bestbuy.com/~assets/bby/_com/header-footer/images/favicon-32.png" sizes="32x32">
  <title>Best Buy International: Select your Country - Best Buy</title>
(...capped)
```

Comment: Thanks, --compressed doesn't work for me on the command line since "installed libcurl version doesn't support this" That wasn't a big deal though, I was primarily going to run code through visual studio anyway, but when I attempted to run code via visual studio I still wasn't able to grab the site. Am I missing something? (I edited the original post with more information)

Thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: @CodyJohnson if your libcurl doesn't support compression, you can try replacing `--compressed` with `--header 'Accept-Encoding: identity'` instead.   ideally you should get a better compiled libcurl though

Comment: you were right, once I updated curl everything seemed to work. I had the recent version installed, issue was windows 10 was defaulting to their version which was last updated in 2017. Everything is all working! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I definitely haven't been using this to try and buy a PS5

Answer (score 1):

**hanshenrik** provided an answer to my direct issue, but along the way I had an additional issue where `--compress` was not available in my installation. For any future people that come across this issue with `--compress` not being available, download an updated version of curl (for example [this](https://curl.se/windows/)) Put the file somewhere permanent like C:\curl\ then add the .exe within the folder. Afterward in the start menu search *Edit the system environment variables*" then in the bottom right click *Environment Variables...* and within the *System variables*(bottom box) find **Path** and click *Edit...* add a new entry giving the file path of your curl install, then move it up in priority above C:Windows\system32

The reason for giving our updated version of curl a higher priority than C:Windows\system32 is in newer versions of Windows 10 curl comes pre-installed in /system32 but that curl version hasn't been updated since 2017 and thus doesn't come with `--compress` If you don't set your curl install to be the higher priority it defaults to Windows 10s older version